# How to Derive the Differential Form of the Contintuity Equation

Tags: fluid-mechanics, mathematics

The book ["Gas Turbine Engineering Handbook"](https://books.google.com/books?id=nEc2OxxT_uMC&pg=PA119&dq=momentum+entering+the+rotor+euler+equation&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkoe3jwYrtAhWrzVkKHTFxDJoQ6AEwAXoECAcQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Boyce, on p.  117 states, the continuity equation,

$ \dot m = \rho A V $,

has as its differential form,

$ 0 = \frac{d\rho}{\rho} + \frac{dA}{A} + \frac{dV}{V}$.

How did the second equation get derived from the first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for $y = f(x_1, ..., x_n)$, the sum of the partial differentials with respect to all of the independent variables is the total differential:
$$ dy = \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_1}dx_1+...+\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_n}dx_n $$

For our case:
$$ \dot{m} = \rho Av$$
$$ d\dot{m} =  \frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial \rho}d\rho + \frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial A}dA+ \frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial v}dv$$
$$\frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial \rho} = vA$$
$$\frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial A} = \rho v$$
$$\frac{\partial \dot{m}}{\partial v} = \rho A$$

Substituting:
$$ d\dot{m} =  Av \ d\rho + \rho v \ dA+ \rho A \ dv $$

for steady-state case, $\dot{m} = \text{const}$, so $d\dot{m} = 0$, then:
$$ Av \ d\rho + \rho v \ dA+ \rho A \ dv = 0 $$

Divide by $\rho A v$:
$$ \boxed{\frac{d\rho}{\rho} + \frac{dA}{A}+ \frac{dv}{v} = 0}$$

Answer (score 2):

the conservation of mass equation  $ \dot m = \rho A V $ may be differentiated to obtain

$A V d\rho + \rho V dA + \rho A dV = 0 $

Which upon division by $ \rho A V $ yields

$ 0 = \frac{d\rho}{\rho} + \frac{dA}{A} + \frac{dV}{V}$.

The method for the first step is "partial derivatives". Explaining this method is outside the scope of the question I believe, but see this screenshot from Wolfram as proof. [image]

Comment: one thing is unclear to me. With respect to what do you differentiate each side of the equation? Do you use the grad / $\nabla$?

Comment: You differentiate with respect to a, b, and c, then add these together.

Comment: so in turn you take partial derivatives in both sides of equation like $\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta\rho}\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta A}\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta V}$ for both sides of the equation? That makes some sense, but still (simpler example to fit the comment but you can extend)  if you do $\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta\rho} \left(\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta A}  \rho A\right)=\frac{\vartheta}{\vartheta\rho} \left(\rho \right)=1$. Apologies if I am being pedantic, I see how the partial derivatives work, but I truly don't see the missing link which makes all fit together .

Comment: Hopefully Algo's nicely formatted answer helps?